# Allow only one instance of a given Core Data Entity

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

What would be the best way to do this, without violating the design principles?

One example would be fetching all previous instances of that entity within awakeFromInsert, and then throwing an exception (or whatever one wants to do) if something is found. But this way is bad, because surely it's not good to access a MOC within a model object.

Comment: Hey, I have provided one example below (in comments to one of the replies). Sorry for the confusion. As for design principles, I'm mostly referring to good MVC design. Just good Cocoa coding :)

Comment: It's safe to access the moc of a mo if you set the moc's `retainRegisteredObjects` to true. I use `UIManagedDocument` for my current project and each document has a root mo which represents the document's contents as if it was a non-Core Data object. This way I get a similar design structure to a normal document with the added object graph management of the Core Data framework. When I create the document I seed the document with the single object. From each subsequent load I instantiate the single object with a lazy property on the document itself and assert that there is only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't actually enforce a singleton pattern on a Core Data object graph. You can try to restrict the insertion of another instance but that is cumbersome.

In my experience, the belief that you need a singleton managed object is an indication of a poor design. Singletons are used for control inside a program. Core Data objects are supposed to represent real-world objects, events or conditions and real-world objects, events and conditions don't appear as singletons or anything like them.

You are probably attempting to put controller or even view logic inside the data model. You might want to rethink you data model.

Comment: Here is an example: Keep an array of the dates the app was launched. Maybe I just want to store such an array for some reasons. What's wrong with wanting to store it right there in the Core Data model? I'd think that would be far more convenient than to, say, create an extra file in the AppSupport folder. I may be wrong. What do you think?

Comment: Totally agree. If you are looking to persist a single instance of a data type then you should probably use NSUserDefaults.

Comment: For example, let's say that singleton would allow me to make sure (bar the user fiddling with the model via sqlite of course) that the user would have to delete the whole data in order to reset a shareware trial. In that case, wouldn't a singleton used for basic storage be warranted for? Again, I may be wrong. I'm always looking for better ideas for how to properly design code.

Comment: sosborn: I'd agree with you there, *if we were talking about a "preference"* which is such that it doesn't really *need* to be stored, as the user can always adjust the app back to the way it was. But what about something that *needs* to be stored?

Comment: The functions you are describing are more app preferences than model layer. Core Data's responsibility is to actually model the data and data logic/behavior. You are trying to use it to control the apps functioning e.g. how many times the app has been launched or forcing the user to delete some data. Those functions have nothing to do with the data model. They are properly in the control layer of a Model-View-Controller design which the iOS employees.

Comment: Despite the name, app state information properly belongs in the user defaults. There is no requirement that all the defaults be exposed to the user and there is no way for the user to edit them beyond the interface you provide. If you still need some other kind of state information save it in a plist.

Comment: I have another case. Inside CoreData I am storing some objects (Books) and some users. Each user has some books. I also have a currently logged in user that has more information than a regular user (posting abilities etc.). This currently logged in user is clearly a subclass of a regular user but there must only be one logged in at a time. What do you recommend I do here?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I actually came across an instance where I wanted to save a single instance of an entity. Here is some example code that might help out others out that come across this.

My solution was to clear an entity (Profile), on saving that same entity to Core Data, if it had >= 1 instance:

```
- (IBAction)saveProfile:(id)sender {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if ([self.profile count] >= 1) {

        NSFetchRequest * allCars = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [allCars setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Profile" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
        [allCars setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];

        NSError * error = nil;
        NSArray * cars = [context executeFetchRequest:allCars error:&error];

        for (NSManagedObject * car in cars) {
            [context deleteObject:car];
        }

        NSError *saveError = nil;
        [context save:&saveError];

    }

    // Create a new managed object
    NSManagedObject *profile = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Profile" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // Code to save information to persistent data store

}
```

As expected, in viewDidLoad I pull the entity's (Profile) information and populate the view if profile == 1 instance:

```
if ([self.profile count] == 1) {
   // Code to pull information from persistent data store and populate the view
}
```